# group objects based on a value

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Been pulling my hair out for a few hours now so its time to get help from SO

I have an array of objects, like this:

```
const data = [
  {city: "London", surname: "jones"},
  {city: "Manchester", surname: "jones"},
  {city: "Leeds", surname: "smith"},
  {city: "Birmingham", surname: "smith"},
  {city: "Rhyl", surname: "clarkson"},
  {city: "Blackpool", surname: "walker"},
  {city: "Rhyl", surname: "walker"},
  {city: "Blackpool", surname: "fletcher"}
];
// Actual data is much more complex, this is just a simplified example
```

I am basically trying to group my data based on a field, in this example `surname`. The surname values are not known before hand, so its needs to be dynamic. So you'd look at the next item in the array, if it matches the previous one its grouped, *but* if it doesnt match then it starts a new group.

the final outcome would look something like this:

```
const outcome = {
  jones: [...2 objects],
  smith: [...2 objects],
  clarkson: [...1 objects],
  walker: [...2 objects],
  fletcher: [...1 objects]
}
```

My initial thought was that I need to loop through each item and compare it with the next, so initially looked at reduce but couldnt get that right, so then I started looping through the items in the `data` array and comparing it with the next one (by getting the index from `map` and incrementing it to see the next item, but this feel really hacky.

algo's and CS isnt my strong point but I feel like the way im doing it is dirty and that there is already a pattern for this as it must be a common task

my next approach would be to loop through each add add something to the data such as a `grouping` id, i.e. `group: 1`, keep an increment and just `++` when ever a `surname` doesnt match the previous, but that still doesnt sound "optimal" as id then have to run a `filter` on each group to get the data in the right format.

**N.B. I've seen several related SO questions to my problem but they miss an important factor about having to sort by a dynamic value, its an easy task if the values are known**

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: *Been pulling my hair out for a few hours* You'd think someone in that mood would react quickly to answers given.

Comment: sorry, it was very late

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to do it.   The `reduce` is the best, that came into my mind.

See the following snippet:

```js
const data = [
  {city: "London", surname: "jones"},
  {city: "Manchester", surname: "jones"},
  {city: "Leeds", surname: "smith"},
  {city: "Birmingham", surname: "smith"},
  {city: "Rhyl", surname: "clarkson"},
  {city: "Blackpool", surname: "walker"},
  {city: "Rhyl", surname: "walker"},
  {city: "Blackpool", surname: "fletcher"}
];

function group(array,field){
    return array.reduce((acc,elem)=>{
        //whether the field value exist
        if(acc[elem[field]]){
            //if the field value exist, push elem to it:
            acc[elem[field]].push(elem)
        }else{
            //if the field value doesn't exist, create an array with elem:
            acc[elem[field]]=[elem]
        }
        //return accumulator for later use
        return acc
    },{})
}

const outcome = group(data,"surname")

console.log(outcome)
```

Comment: awesome, thanks. selected as the answer as I feel its more descriptive for anyone else finding this questions.

Comment: @atmd Do you wish the `surname` property to be part of the objects in the array?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [groupBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#groupBy) from lodash :

```
import { groupBy } from 'lodash'

const result = groupBy(data, item => item.surname)
```

The result will be :

```
{ jones:
   [ { city: 'London', surname: 'jones' },
     { city: 'Manchester', surname: 'jones' } ],
  smith:
   [ { city: 'Leeds', surname: 'smith' },
     { city: 'Birmingham', surname: 'smith' } ],
  clarkson: [ { city: 'Rhyl', surname: 'clarkson' } ],
  walker:
   [ { city: 'Blackpool', surname: 'walker' },
     { city: 'Rhyl', surname: 'walker' } ],
  fletcher: [ { city: 'Blackpool', surname: 'fletcher' } ] }
```

Comment: "You *need* to use groupBy from lodash", need is a strong word, especially for things that aren't needed.

Comment: That sounds aggressive :/ Sorry for this junvar

Answer (score 1):

Using a combination of a list of unique keys (de-duplicated using a `Set`), `reduce`, `map` and `filter` works:

```js
const data = [
  {city: "London", surname: "jones"},
  {city: "Manchester", surname: "jones"},
  {city: "Leeds", surname: "smith"},
  {city: "Birmingham", surname: "smith"},
  {city: "Rhyl", surname: "clarkson"},
  {city: "Blackpool", surname: "walker"},
  {city: "Rhyl", surname: "walker"},
  {city: "Blackpool", surname: "fletcher"}
];

const result = [...new Set(data.map(x => x.surname))]
  .reduce((acc, val) => { 
    return {...acc, [val]: [...(data
        .filter(x => x.surname === val)
        .map(x => { return { city: x.city } }))]};
  }, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you want to handle persons with the same surname that do not occur continuously. E.g.: jones, jones, smith, jones?

If you would like to group them all, reduce is pretty simple to use as it's designed for this use case essentially:

```js
const data = [
  {city: "London", surname: "jones"},
  {city: "Manchester", surname: "jones"},
  {city: "Leeds", surname: "smith"},
  {city: "Birmingham", surname: "smith"},
  {city: "Rhyl", surname: "clarkson"},
  {city: "Blackpool", surname: "walker"},
  {city: "Rhyl", surname: "walker"},
  {city: "Blackpool", surname: "fletcher"}
];

let grouped = data.reduce((acc, d) => {
  acc[d.surname] = acc[d.surname] || [];
  acc[d.surname].push(d.city);
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(grouped);
```

If you'd like to overwrite previous sequences of the same surname (e.g. `jones, jones, smith, jones` would map to 1 smith and 1 (the last) jones), then you can also keep track of the previous person iterated and compare surnames:

```js
const data = [
  {city: "London", surname: "jones"},
  {city: "Manchester", surname: "jones"},
  {city: "Leeds", surname: "smith"},
  {city: "Birmingham", surname: "smith"},
  {city: "Rhyl", surname: "clarkson"},
  {city: "Blackpool", surname: "walker"},
  {city: "Rhyl", surname: "walker"},
  {city: "Blackpool", surname: "fletcher"},
  {city: "non-continuous jones", surname: "jones"},
];

let grouped = data.reduce(([acc, prevSurname], d) => {
  if (prevSurname !== d.surname)
    acc[d.surname] = [];
  acc[d.surname].push(d.city);
  return [acc, d.surname];
}, [{}])[0];

console.log(grouped);
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, use reduce and add objects based on surname key

```js
const data = [
  {city: "London", surname: "jones"},
  {city: "Manchester", surname: "jones"},
  {city: "Leeds", surname: "smith"},
  {city: "Birmingham", surname: "smith"},
  {city: "Rhyl", surname: "clarkson"},
  {city: "Blackpool", surname: "walker"},
  {city: "Rhyl", surname: "walker"},
  {city: "Blackpool", surname: "fletcher"}
];

console.log(data.reduce((acc,v)=> {
   acc[v.surname]? (acc[v.surname].push(v)) : (acc[v.surname] =[v])
  return acc
}, {}))
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/EJdamx?editors=1010

Comment: @connexo, i have deleted my old answer and by mistake copied snippet and forgot to add details of my post

Comment: @connexo, added now